# Calling in data frame columns in for loop

Tags: r, excel, csv

I am trying to call in a column from a data frame in a for loop. I have a vector containing characters that is being used to iterate through the for loop. I would like to store the column from a data frame in a vector while in  the for loop so I can do calculations on the vector.

The problem I am having is using the character to reference the data frame column.

So far I have:

```
  for(i in names){
  
  displacement <- `i`["Displacement"]
  load <- `i`["Load"]
  
}
```

names is a character vector containing the names of the data frames stored in the environment. The names are in the format of specimen1, specimen2, etc up to specimen32.

If I type the following into the console:

```
specimen1["Displacement"]
```

I get a list containing the displacement values, confirmed by:

```
> typeof(specimen1["Displacement"])
[1] "list"
```

When I run my for loop, and type displacement in the console I get:

```
> displacement
[1] NA
```

The same happens for load as well.

Is it because I'm trying to define a list as a vector?

I tried using `unlist()`, but it was not the format that I wanted. It contained the heading of the displacement column as well as the actual displacement value.

Comment: To index a column in a DF, you need to call it like `df[,'column_name']` or `df$column_name`. Look at this tut: http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-frame-column-vector

Comment: `get` is a function that is meant to handle such cases.

Comment: What you get isn't merely a list but still a data.frame. All data frames are lists at heart. Just like a list, if you use df['colname'] it will subset the list, while preserving its listness, or in this case data.frameness. You can also get the collumn as a vector by  df[['colname']].

Comment: Okay, so using > specimen1[,'Displacement'] in the console, I return a vector. But when I try to use this syntax in my for loop, eg i[,'Displacement']` I get an error saying: Error in i[, "Displacement"] : incorrect number of dimensions